# firefox not rendering proper width to my table's header

Tags: html, css

th border and td border doesn't align in firefox but they do in chrome.
I want my table to be alingned perfectly that is why I have hard coded width and everything yet firefox is not recognising it. Also I can see the width specified in inspect element is different from which I am providing in both browsers.
In chrome it is alright but fire fox is not helping me at all.
thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
  th,td{
 border-right:2px solid blue;
 border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table id="example3" style="display:inline-block;"">
     <thead style="background-color: wheat">
     <tr>
         <th width="50px"><input style="float:left" type="checkbox"></th>
         <th width="180px">Model</th>
         <th width="180px">Color</th>
         <th width="180px">Year</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody style="display:inline-block;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-
         y:auto;height:100px;">
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span>
        </td></tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span><input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input 
        type="text"></td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span>
        <input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input type="text">
        </td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td></tr>
     <tr><td width="50px"><input type="checkbox"></td><td width="180px">
        <span>
        <input type="text"></span></td><td width="180px"><input type="text">
        </td><td width="180px"><span><input type="text"></span></td></tr>
     </tbody>

     </table>
     <input type="button" id="add" value="add">
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: remove display:inline-block; <tbody style="display:inline-block;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-
         y:auto;height:100px;">

Comment: I can not. I need a scrolling body

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS.

```
th, td{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

It looks like the borders are causing the widths to increase.

Without adding this CSS property to an element, a border will always increase the size of it.

Comment: I tried that too, but it seems like firefox is messing up my header. As I said chrome is alright